# Create new mode (with specific key binding) in VIM?

Tags: vi, vim

Say I have several opened buffer in current tab, I want to easily resize them, so I do mapping something like this:

```
nnoremap <c-j> <c-w><
nnoremap <c-k> <c-w>>
nnoremap <c-l> <c-w>+
nnoremap <c-h> <c-w>-
```

Since I don't normally need to resize it, and I've pretty-much used up my ctrl-key mappings, I want to enable this kind of mapping only when I press a certain key.

For example, I define a "resize-mode", and  to enable it. After I press , the key-binding of  (and others) would be changed to the above; and after I press  again, these key-bindings would be changed back.

How to achieve that..?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I've started using the `submode` plugin for things like this, and while I haven't used it extensively, it's working well for me so far.

Answer (score 4):

I generally like the splits to be of equal size, however in times when I need to focus on a particular split, rather than re-sizing it the way you mention, I would like to recommend a few other approaches :

1. Open the current split in a new tab, read / change however you want and just `:q` to get back to the previous tab as it is, with all the splits intact. In VIM you can do this by `:tab split` on a split, it just opens the current split in a new tab keeping the older tab intact.
2. VIM has a `:resize [N]` and `:vertical resize [N]` where N specifies the height / width of the split respectively. Use these instead of the mappings if you feel they are awkward. **NOTE**: You can also use `:resize +N`, `:resize -N`, `:vertical resize +N` and `:vertical resize -N` for changing the height / width relative to the present value.
3. VIM's `:resize [N]` and `:vertical resize [N]` resizes the current split to it's maximum size if you omit the `[N]`, so `:resize` will make the window occupy the entire height of the screen and `:vertical resize` will make the window occupy the entire width of the screen. VIM also offers mappings for these and they are <kbd><C-w>_</kbd> and <kbd><C-w>|</kbd>. You can use these to temporarily maximize the current split and work on it, when done, just hit <kbd><C-w>=</kbd> to adjust the size of all splits equally.
4. (not recommended) If you must define your own mapping and the previous options don't suit you, you can always prefix your mappings with the <kbd><Leader></kbd>, which can be configured separately in your vimrc.

Comment: Thanks for the :tab split, I never know that before :)

Comment: Another option is `Ctrl-W_T` -- similar to `:tab sp`.

Comment: @mMontu Ctrl-W_T is not the same as `:tab sp`, Ctrl-W_T moves the split to a new tab, `:tab sp` just copies it, so the original split in the original tab remains intact.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I said it is similar :)

I thought you might add it. My workflow is similar to what you describe on the first and third point, but sometimes I prefer to move instead of duplicating the view of buffer, as I know I will be done with that buffer when I finish reading/editing it.

Answer (score 2):

You may not have noticed it, but `<C-w>` actually puts you in "window management" mode and for what it's worth, resizing windows is much better with the mouse.

Comment: Haha that's a valid point :) The only problem with <C-w> is that.. it's not persistent -- it's lost after I press another key..

Comment: @songyy there are plugins like vim-submode and a few more that try to solve that use-case. It allows to create submodes like <C-w> which would persist and allows subsequent key presses to be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a toggle command or mapping. In it, check whether the mappings are currently active or not, and undefine (or restore) / define them. Restoring (I think that's what you want, as you're running out of mappings) is easier when you define the temporary overlap mappings with `<buffer>`; this way, the original mappings are not lost, they just are temporarily overridden.

```
function! ToggleMappings()
    if empty(maparg('<C-j>', 'n'))
        nnoremap <buffer> <c-j> <c-w><
        nnoremap <buffer> <c-k> <c-w>>
        nnoremap <buffer> <c-l> <c-w>+
        nnoremap <buffer> <c-h> <c-w>-
    else
        nunmap <buffer> <c-j>
        nunmap <buffer> <c-k>
        nunmap <buffer> <c-l>
        nunmap <buffer> <c-h>
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>w :call ToggleMappings()<CR>
command! ToggleMappings call ToggleMappings()
```